# How to exit calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way of exiting a function that has called the function that's currently executing?

An example would be:

```
function doOneTwoThree(){

    doStuff(1, print);

    doStuff(2, print);

    doStuff(3, print);

}

function doStuff(parameter, aFunction){

    if(parameter === 2) {
        //exit from doOneTwoThree
    }

    aFunction(parameter);
}

function print(something){

    console.log(something);

}
```

Another option would be to return an error in `doStuff` and check for that error in `doOneTwoThree` every time I call `doStuff`. But i would like not to have to check for it every time...

Comment: You could always just throw a javascript error on purpose.

Comment: `return` would return to the calling function, though? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: No... you are essentially trying to pop two stack frames off the call stack at one time and you cannot do that.

Comment: Exactly what @Daedalus said.  I would think the real solution is to move the parameter check in method doOneTwoThree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `throw` and catch the error throw in `doOneTwoThree`:

```
function doStuff(parameter, aFunction) {
    if (parameter === 2) {
        throw "error";
    }
}

function doOneTwoThree() {
    try {
        doStuff(1, print);
        doStuff(2, print);
    }
    catch (error) { /* handle here */ }
}
```

*However*, if you are not throwing an actual error/exception, you should *not* use this to control your code flow.  Instead, you should check the return value of the `doStuff` call to confirm that you can continue on.  If that sounds unclean to you, you could also do something like chain `doStuff` calls or call them in a loop that you can break out of based on the `doStuff` return value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this? return a token/magic value?  (a string like 'eek' is probably a bad token, but it amused me, use an int instead )

```
function doOneTwoThree(){

    if (doStuff(1, print) === "eek") return;

    doStuff(2, print);

    doStuff(3, print);

}

function doStuff(parameter, aFunction){

    if(parameter === 2) {
        return "eek";
    }

    aFunction(parameter);
}
```